# When I try to use ajax, chrome's console says ""Resource failed to load"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to download a javascript file using ajax. But I can't do it.

Google chrome console says `Resource failed to load`

Here is my html. Please check it and give me comments.

https://www.box.com/s/b2mj0cs7xbdqh8sdrh92

Comment: And da codez, we need da codez, homez!

Comment: jQuery has [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for this purpose (and note that there are security restrictions that may come into play). Copy and paste the *Javascript* into your question and select and format it with the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `GET` as your request type. So your new code would read,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all-min.js",
    dataType: "script"
    });
```

Also make sure that `jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all-min.js` exists in the same directory as `index.htm`. This still won't load it directly into the page, but would be able to access the text and then manipulate it however you want.

Comment: I tried to use your code.Then I was get an error massage from chrome's console.Console said to me "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/zemi.01/zemi123001/jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all-min.js. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: That means that you can't access the file because of permissions. However, why don't you just include the script in your `<script>` declarations? Such as, `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all-min.‌​js"></script>`? That way you don't have to load it with jQuery and it will be loaded at the start of the document.

Answer (score 0):

In my opionion, AJax shouldn't be used to download resource files, but rather to communicate with the server from the client.  Too many implications in the former.

What is your expected outcome with loading the js file?

If you're really intending on doing this (and I wouldn't suggest it), use jQuery.getScript():

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: I want to apply jsPlumb's event to a div created by function. I will use JQuery.getScript();.4